# UNIX make directory that appears to have contents of other directories

Tags: linux, unix

If I have 2 directories, a and b can anyone suggest a convenient method of creating a directory that appears to have the contents of both a and b without copying the files ? At the moment what I have been using is ln -s * to make a load of sym links and then delete the sym links when I am done. I would prefer it though if the contents of sub directories appeared to be merged, and managing this with the sym link method may need some fiddling.

It's OK if the resultant directory is read only given the application.

Comment: Can't you just symlink the directory itself instead of all its contents? I.e. `ln -s a/ b` would create a symlinked directory `b` that points to `a`.

Comment: @Daniel Andersson That would not create a directory appearing to show the merged contents of a and b which was the point of the question.

Comment: It is kind of non-trivial. How do you merge collisions for files contained in both a and b? What is your intention? You can try to hard-link files from a and b to another directory c, so you get files update on change in both directories.

Comment: I know it's non trivial, I'd like collisions to make whichever file is newest appear in the merged directory. I can't see how hard linking helps at all over soft linking though, and it won't work if a and b are on different drives.

Comment: Which OS/distro are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by “I would prefer it though if the contents of sub directories appeared to be merged”?  Try aliasing `ls` to `ls -L` and see if that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively merge to directories with [UnionFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS) by overlaying the two directories (called branches in this context) into one single mount point.

There are several implementations of UnionFS; [UnionFsFuse](http://podgorny.cz/unionfs-fuse) is one of the simpler ones, since it is an application (rather than a kernel patch).

The website contains a link to their archive. Compiling the source code should be straightforward on most distros.

In Ubuntu, e.g., it suffices to install the package **unionfs-fuse** by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unionfs-fuse
```

Once installed, you can proceed to overlay the directories. There are a variety of options. I'll briefly explain the most basic ones:

- The command

  ```
    unionfs-fuse foo:bar baz
  ```

  overlays the contents of the directories *foo* and *bar* in the directory *baz*.<sup>1</sup>

  This overlay will be read-only; any attempt to create or modify a file in *baz* will result in a *Permission denied.* error. However, you'll still be able to create and modify the files inside *foo* and *bar* themselves.

  Collisions are handled in a fixed way: If a file exists in a higher branch (*foo*), it will have preference over a file of the same name in a lower branch (*bar*).
- The command

  ```
    union-fuse foo=RW:bar=RO baz
  ```

  makes *foo* writable and *bar* (read-only). Modifying files of *foo* will be possible, but modifying files of *bar* won't be. All newly created files in *baz* will appear in *foo*.
- The command

  ```
    union-fuse -ocow foo=RW:bar=RO baz
  ```

  is similar to the last command. The *copy on write* option (`cow`) has the effect that attempting to modify a file of *bar* inside *baz* will result in a modified copy of the file in *foo* (or any other higher-level writable branch).
- With the command

  ```
    union-fuse foo=RW:bar=RW baz
  ```

  all can be modified. New files will be created in the top branch (*foo*).
- The command

  ```
    union-fuse foo=RO:bar=RW baz
  ```

  allows modifying the files of *bar* inside *baz*, but no new files can be created.
- The command

  ```
    sudo umount baz
  ```

  undoes the union mount.

See also: [man unionfs-fuse](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/unionfs-fuse.8.html)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *baz* must exist before this command is executed. This applies to all further commands as well.</sub>